# AMP: track which option was selected with amp-analytics

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics

I am trying to fire a tracking event when an option is selected inside a `<select>` tag.

With `amp-analytics` I am able to send a `click` tracking event when an element is clicked, but only with certain elements like `<select>` `<a>` and `<div>`.

I can understand why a click event wouldn't be fired on an `<option>` element but I was wondering how to track that an option was selected. Below is my code that will fire on the click of the `<select>` but not on the click of an `<option>`

```
<body>
  <select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
  </select>
  <amp-analytics>
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "requests": {
          "event": "https://www.example.com?message=${message}"
        },
        "triggers": {
          "selectClicked": {
            "on": "click",
            "request": "event",
            "selector": "select",
            "vars": {
              "message": "clicked_select"
            }
          },
          "optionClicked": {
            "on": "click",
            "request": "event",
            "selector": "option",
            "vars": {
              "message": "clicked_option"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </amp-analytics>
</body>
```

It looks amp-analytics only supports a couple Triggers:
`render-start`
`ini-load`
`click`
`scroll`
`timer`
`visible`
`hidden`
`user-error`
`access-*`
`video-*`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Try following the sample for [Anchor Clicks](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-analytics/#anchor-clicks), it provides a very difinitive sample and code implementation that might help you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea that's the same style as how I am tracking the click of the `select` however it doesn't work for `option` elements